# Div isn't scrollable on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, browser, cross-browser

I've built js app that inserts a form widget into a site. The form is scrollable on all other major browsers except for Firefox. There is `overflow-y: auto` in the div
in question, but firefox doesn't seem to respond to it

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJRi3.png)
[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZeKh.png)

see demo down here
https://stickyform.co

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You need to remove display:flex on elements with class:(.sf-modal-body)

Comment: that resolves the issue! yes it did not need the flex at all. The firefox discrepancy is still odd, but it won't matter. Thanks @hamid

Comment: You'r welcome! :)